# How to read out the number in addresses in Canadian French?

Tags: prononciation, québec

The following is a (fake) Canadian address:

```
3008 Boulevard Leblanc Bureau 318
Ste-Noémie-de-Woburn, SK P9Z7Q6
```

How do you read out the first number in the first line?
For example, digit by digit? Or in groups of two digits? Or as an actual number (containing thousands, etc.)? Or are all of these valid option? What if it contains six digits?

And is there a difference between the way you read the first or the second number?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we usually say in Montreal:

52 Ste Catherine = "Cinquante-deux"

524 Ste-Catherine = "Cinq-cent-vingt-quatre"

5235 Ste-Catherine" = "Cinquante-deux Trente-cinq"

12325 Ste-Catherine = "Douze Trois-cent-vingt-cinq"

In your example, most people will say "Trente-zéro-huit", some will say "Trois-mille-huit", none will say "Trois-zéro-zéro-huit"

Comment: À mon avis, il se pourrait qu'on dise trois-zéro-zéro-huit si l'interlocuteur ne comprend pas, comme on épellerait un mot... Mais oui, trente-zéro-huit +1 C'est davantage relié à la mnémotechnique qu'à la langue je crois. Merci !

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste Je crois que c'est aussi lié à la division des villes en rues et avenues numérotées: dans bien des villes (au moins dans l'Ouest et le Nord canadiens, avec lesquels je suis plus familier), au saute par exemple de 3017 à 3101 lorsque l'on franchit la 31e rue, ce qui permet facilement de trouver le bloc auquel appartient une adresse donnée.

Comment: Par ailleurs, *«trois mille huit»* s'entend parfois, mais aussitôt passé la dizaine, *«trois mille douze»* devient très très rare, et *«trente douze»* à peu près universel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in Canadian French, but without any doubts, in French French it is said:

> Trois mille-huit Boulevard Leblanc Bureau trois cent dix-huit